# Angular SPA Path to Assets Not Resolving With Base Href

Tags: angular, path, web-deployment

I am developing an Angular Single Page App based upon the ASP.Net Core template. Part of the project involves displaying a 3D model using Three.js. In one of my components I am reading a 3D model file (.gltf) from a directory in my `assets` folder. No matter what I try I cannot get the path to the model file to resolve.

So far I have set `angular.json` `options` as follows:

```
"outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            ...
```

`package.json` `scripts` as follows:

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod --extract-css --base-href /3d-explorer/",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  ...
```

To load the model in my component I set the URL as follows:

```
const modelUrl = './assets/models/DNB_Boiler_Gas_Circ.gltf';
```

In IIS my application has an alias which matches my base href ('3d-explorer').

When browsing the website in Chrome, all the navigation works fine between multiple Angular Modules and my logo on the Home page loads fine from the `assets` folder using the following code:

```
<img src="./assets/images/indigo-3d-explorer@72dpi-01.png" />
```

...but the static model file just doesn't want to know. If it is any help, the only way I used to be able to get the site to work was in IIS to set the website to the `dist` folder which is created on the production build and not the root directory. I don't want to continue with this though because soon I will be using the .Net Core aspect to develop my Web API. To be clear, I build the website using the following command:

```
dotnet publish --configuration Release --output "C:\3dExplorer\Publish\v1.0.11_2019-12-10"
```

This places the following within the build folder:

```
ClientApp
wwwroot
appsettings.Development
appsettings.json
ProjectName.deps.json
ProjectName.dll
etc.
```

Inside `ClientApp` is my `dist` folder, and within this is my `assets` folder along with all of my javascript files and `index.html`.

On attempting to load the model file, I get an error `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`. This appears to be because the `Index.html` page is being returned, not the model file, and so the first character in the html page is '<', not what the loader is expecting!

I can't see the wood for the trees now! Any advice or suggestions would be very welcome.

Comment: don't use `./`, in absolute paths, just use `/assets`

Comment: Good suggestion Akash but this still didn't work. I tries `assets` and `/assets`, neither worked. Checking the Network tab in Chrome dev tools, the Request URL looks ok and the Status Code is 200, but the Response is the HTML from `Index.html`.

Comment: I feel that the browser may be looking within the `wwwroot` folder for the static file. Could this be the case?